# largest prime remainder from three consecutive primes

Tags: prime-numbers

From three consecutive primes 89 results from $223*211mod199$=89.  Is this the largest prime remainder?  For p(n)=then nth prime, the form is p(n+1)*p(n+2)modp(n)=prime.

Comment: What's the question?

Comment: The remainder is 89.  Using the general form, can you find a larger prime remainder

Comment: I'll ask you if you think 89 is the largest such remainder.

Comment: How far have you searched?  If $p_{n+1},p_{n+2}$ are "fairly near" $p_n$ then of course the product will be even $\mod {p_n}$.  I'd expect it to be even "most" of the time.  Accordingly, any useful search would have to go pretty deep.

Comment: It seems that you agree that 89 is the largest prime remainder.  If not, one would need a few large prime gap, which may NOT exist.  If nothing else, you learnt something about 89.

Comment: So, how far have you searched?

Comment: I stopped once I found 89, then probed larger trios of consecutive primes to see that 89 will be hard to surpass.  One could investigate p(n+1)*p(n+2)*p(n+3)mod p(n)=prime remainder.

Comment: A quick search did not find a larger remainder up to $p(10^7)$

Comment: Looks like 89 is the winner!  Thanx for exercising your electrons.

Answer (score 0):

THIS IS NOT A COMPREHENSIVE ANSWER, rather an  extended comment that is too long for the 'comment' section.

Consider three consecutive prime numbers $p_n,\ p_{n+1},\ p_{n+2}$ with gaps $g_1=p_{n+1}-p_n$ and $g_2=p_{n+2}-p_{n+1}$. For all $p_n>2$, $g_1$ and $g_2$ are even.

$p_{n+1}\equiv g_1\mod{p_n}$ and $p_{n+2}\equiv g_1+g_2\mod{p_n}$ so $(p_{n+1})(p_{n+2})\equiv (g_1)(g_1+g_2)\mod{p_n}$.

Unless $(g_1)(g_1+g_2)>p_n$, $(g_1)(g_1+g_2)\mod{p_n}$ will be even and hence composite (see comment by lulu). Thus as larger candidate $p_n$ are examined, it would be necessary to focus on primes separated by larger gaps.

The size of gaps is subject to limits. In general $g_1\le \alpha p_n$, or $p_{n+1}\le (1+\alpha )p_n$ and $p_{n+2}\le (1+\alpha )p_{n+1}=(1+\alpha )^2p_n\approx (1+2\alpha )p_n$. So $\max(g_1)=(1+\alpha )p_n-p_n=\alpha p_n$ and $\max((g_1+g_2))\approx(1+2\alpha )p_n-p_n=2\alpha p_n$.

Thus $\max((g_1)(g_1+g_2))\approx 2{\alpha}^2{p_n}^2$. For $(g_1)(g_1+g_2)>p_n$ it must be the case that $p_n>\frac{1}{2{\alpha}^2}$.

For numbers greater than $2\cdot 10^7$, Schoenfeld [cited here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bertrand%27s_postulate) has given a numerical limit $\alpha \le \frac{1}{16597}$ requiring $p_n>\frac{16597^2}{2}\approx1.3\cdot 10^8$. Other non-numeric limits on $\alpha$ are also given in the Wikipedia article, which may be even smaller than the value of Schoenfeld. Note that even if candidates with $(g_1)(g_1+g_2)>p_n$ are found, there is no guarantee that the residue generated will be prime. This suggests that very large primes (much greater than those examined by gammatester) will have to be examined in the search for a prime remainder larger than $89$.

Comment: Put 89 into the category of UNsolved problems in number theory?

Comment: For (p(n+1)-x)*(p(n+2)-x)>x  for the first even number > x subtract x from this even number to see if it is prime.  The gap would have to be very, very large from p(n) to p(n+1).